# Using GIT in production Rails machines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, deployment, production

Should my production Rails project use GIT? it will be easy for me to update the 
servers and to push hot fixes, but what if I'll have a conflict during a pull?
and if I'll accidentally pull something wrong it make cause some downtime.

What is your advice on how to synch between the GIT repository & production?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using a dedicated deployment system like [Capistrano](http://capify.org)? It solves many of the issues you are trying to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

Don't leave local changes on your production machines, and there is no risk of conflicts.

Production installs should pull from a dedicated branch/tag (e.g. use [gitflow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/), production machines pull from the latest tag or simply master) - not the branch you regularly push to (develop, if you use git-flow).